# Multiply two columns and produce result in third column

Tags: mysql

I want to multiply two columns( Quantity and Price) and produce the result in third column (Total). Please guide me how to do this.

[image]

Comment: why not select the result in a computed column?

Comment: It is not recommended to store computed values in DB. You can compute any time you need.

Comment: that operation is which time you want to perform at the insertion time or else at retrieve  time  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **`not recommended to store computed values in DB`**. You can compute any time you need.

By any way for your need you can update it like this,

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME set Total=Quantity*Price
```

You can also create triggers if needed,

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT
ON TABLE_NAME
FOR insert
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET TABLE_NAME.Total=TABLE_NAME.Quantity+TABLE_NAME.Price
```